# Programmatically adding Static IP's

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-server-2008, ip, netsh

I am writing a small application to automated a lot of the stuff we have to do on a daily basis when setting up new machines. I have a whopping 18 new boxes to setup now, so I really need to get this little feature added which allows me to more easily add IP Addresses.

My function which generates the subnet based on the block number works fine, but I would like to be able to input something like 192.168.1.10/29 and have it add all 5 IP Addresses to the NIC. My function for adding the IP's works fine, but my question is...

Do I need to manually code it like this? (Obviously psuedo code and not a working example)

```
int 29block = 5
int 28block = 12

for (i = 0; i<29block; i++)
{
     string ip = ipinputbox.text;
     ip = ip + 2 + i; // 2 being the value to compensate for gateway/etc.
     AddIpAddress(ip);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What 5 addresses would be added for your example, `192.168.1.10/29`?

Comment: Here is one of our blocks 72.26.196.160/29. So .162 - .166 would be the addresses I needed to add to the NIC.

Comment: Since `72.26.196.160/29` includes as valid hosts all those in the range `.161` to `.166`, how is the program to know the actual range should only include `.162` to `.166`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've whipped up a class that can interpret a subnet address and return an enumerable collection of the addresses represented by that subnet.  So for example, the ip subnet `192.168.1.10/29` should return all the addresses after (and including) `192.168.1.10` that fall in the subnet represented by `/29`, which is mask `255.255.255.248`. There are six valid hosts in this subnet, `.9` to `.14`.  So the list returned would be

```
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13
192.168.1.14
```

Here is the sample code I'm using (in LINQPad): http://pastebin.com/d6EE2bpj, and the sample output generated by the test code:

```
==192.168.1.10/29==
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13
192.168.1.14
==72.26.196.160/29==
72.26.196.161
72.26.196.162
72.26.196.163
72.26.196.164
72.26.196.165
72.26.196.166
```

The code generates the bit mask on the fly based on the subnet size, so it should be completely generic for any starting ip address and any subnet size.

Comment: @BrettPowell: Just wanted to follow up, have you gotten a chance to use the code in production, and is it working as expected?